# Substring-based method not running properly

Tags: java, substring

I'm creating a set of methods that displays a row of a playing board based on an input string, and stores it in a string which I will later call up. My code is as follows:

```
public class A1Program {

    public void start() {
        String inputString = "XOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXO";
        int row = 1;
        int length = inputString.length();

    }

    private String extractRow(int row, String inputString) {
        String rowString1 = inputString.substring(row, row + 1);
        String rowString2 = inputString.substring(row + 6, row + 7);
        String rowString3 = inputString.substring(row + 12, row + 13);
        String rowString4 = inputString.substring(row + 18, row + 19);
        String rowString5 = inputString.substring(row + 24, row + 25);
        String rowString6 = inputString.substring(row + 30, row + 31);
        String rowString7 = inputString.substring(row + 36, row + 37);


        return rowString1 + "|" + rowString2 + "|" + rowString3 + "|" + rowString4 + "|" + rowString5
                + "|" + rowString6 + "|" + rowString7 + "|";

    }

    private void displayBoard(String extractRow) {
        System.out.println(extractRow + "-----------");
    }
}
```

When I run the code, nothing is displayed, but I am expecting it to display a row of the board...(extractRow).

Comment: You never call `displayBoard(...)` (or `extractRow`).

Comment: ... or any of the other methods. displayBoard appears to be ignoring half the inputString for no apparent reason.

Comment: also you use extractRow as a function name and a paramater

Comment: I would start with the simplest program which displays something add something to it to add functionality. Writing lots of code and trying to fix it later is very hard.

Answer (score 1):

you never call extractRow and displayBoard methods.

Call these methods inside start method your code will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Except that there's nothing behaviorally wrong with your code once you actually call it, you should really do the job in a loop:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
  displayBoard(extractRow(0, "XOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXO"));
}
private static String extractRow(int row, String inputString) {
  final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < 37; i+=6) b.append(inputString.charAt(i)).append('|');
  return b.toString();
}
private static void displayBoard(String extractRow) {
  System.out.println(extractRow + "-----------");
}
```

This prints the same thing as your code:

```
X|X|X|X|X|X|X|-----------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it may print something out.

```
public class A1Program {

    public void start() {
        String inputString = "XOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXO";
        int row = 1;
        int length = inputString.length();
        //check here
        displayBoard(extractRow(row, inputString));

    }

    private String extractRow(int row, String inputString) {
        String rowString1 = inputString.substring(row, row + 1);
        String rowString2 = inputString.substring(row + 6, row + 7);
        String rowString3 = inputString.substring(row + 12, row + 13);
        String rowString4 = inputString.substring(row + 18, row + 19);
        String rowString5 = inputString.substring(row + 24, row + 25);
        String rowString6 = inputString.substring(row + 30, row + 31);
        String rowString7 = inputString.substring(row + 36, row + 37);


        return rowString1 + "|" + rowString2 + "|" + rowString3 + "|" + rowString4 + "|" + rowString5
                + "|" + rowString6 + "|" + rowString7 + "|";

    }

    private void displayBoard(String extractRow) {
        System.out.println(extractRow + "-----------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class A1Program {

```
private String extractRow(int row, String inputString) {
    String rowString1 = inputString.substring(row, row + 1);
    String rowString2 = inputString.substring(row + 6, row + 7);
    String rowString3 = inputString.substring(row + 12, row + 13);
    String rowString4 = inputString.substring(row + 18, row + 19);
    String rowString5 = inputString.substring(row + 24, row + 25);
    String rowString6 = inputString.substring(row + 30, row + 31);
    String rowString7 = inputString.substring(row + 36, row + 37);


    return rowString1 + "|" + rowString2 + "|" + rowString3 + "|" + rowString4 + "|" + rowString5
            + "|" + rowString6 + "|" + rowString7 + "|";

}

private void displayBoard(String extractRow) {
    System.out.println(extractRow + "-----------");
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    A1Program a = new A1Program();
    a.displayBoard(a.extractRow(0, "XOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXO"));
}
```

}

Try this you will see expected result